# Multiple Elements animation delay - css

Tags: html, jquery, css, sass, css-selectors

I have a svg for alphabet "Z", and i am trying to make it as a loader for my website and I am trying to animate it, "Z" have 3 lines, top middle & bottom. I want them to appear one by one, like when loader starts, top line of "Z" appears from left, then middle line and then bottom line will appear. I am trying to make animation but if i do it for infinite then it doesn't work fine, I have also tried `animation-delay` but didn't work for me.
Here is my code:

```css
/* Boilerplat - skip it */
*{box-sizing: border-box}html { box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 16px; } *, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; } body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-weight: normal; } ol, ul { list-style: none; } img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }body{height: 100vh; display: flex; align-items: center}

/* Actual Code below */
.ZLogo{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 12px 18px; 
}
.topBar,
.bottomBar{
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  animation: topBar 2s infinite;
}
.middleBar{
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px 60px 0px);
  animation: middleBar 2s infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.bottomBar{
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  animation: bottomBar 2s infinite;
 animation-delay: 2s;
  
}

@keyframes topBar {
  0%   {
    clip-path: inset(0px 26px 0px 0px);
  }
  50%  {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 26px 0px 0px);
  }
}

@keyframes middleBar {
  0%   {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  }
  50%  {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 60px 0px);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  }
}
@keyframes bottomBar {
  0%   {
    clip-path: inset(0px 26px 0px 0px);
  }
  50%  {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 26px 0px 0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="ZLogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="56" viewBox="0 0 40 56" fill="none">
<path class="topBar" d="M0 8.90909V0H24.3536L17.9448 8.90909H0Z" fill="black"/>
<path class="middleBar" d="M41.0166 7.63636V0H32.0442L0 48.3636V56H8.97238L41.0166 7.63636Z" fill="black"/>
<path class="bottomBar" d="M17.9448 56L24.3536 48.3636H41.0166V56H17.9448Z" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

Please help me to animate it fine, I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing of the animation can be described within the keyframes:

```css
/* Boilerplat - skip it */
*{box-sizing: border-box}html { box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 16px; } *, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; } body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-weight: normal; } ol, ul { list-style: none; } img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }body{height: 100vh; display: flex; align-items: center}

/* Actual Code below */
.ZLogo{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 12px 18px; 
}

.topBar,
.bottomBar {
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  animation: topBar 2s infinite;
}

.middleBar {
  clip-path: inset(0px 0px 60px 0px);
  animation: middleBar 2s infinite;
}

.bottomBar {
  clip-path: inset(0px 26px 0px 0px);
  animation: bottomBar 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes topBar {
  0% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 26px 0px 0px);
  }
  17% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  }
  83% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 26px 0px 0px);
  }
}

@keyframes middleBar {
  17% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 60px 0px);
  }
  33% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  }
  67% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  }
  83% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 60px 0px);
  }
}

@keyframes bottomBar {
  33% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 26px 0px 0px);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px);
  }
  67% {
    clip-path: inset(0px 26px 0px 0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="ZLogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="56" viewBox="0 0 40 56" fill="none">
<path class="topBar" d="M0 8.90909V0H24.3536L17.9448 8.90909H0Z" fill="black"/>
<path class="middleBar" d="M41.0166 7.63636V0H32.0442L0 48.3636V56H8.97238L41.0166 7.63636Z" fill="black"/>
<path class="bottomBar" d="M17.9448 56L24.3536 48.3636H41.0166V56H17.9448Z" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's good, thanks brother, but when animation ends, it's going back like reverse. It should not go reverse, it should hide and again start animation

Comment: @ZainShabir you're welcome :) That's how the animation was in the question, so I thought that was intentional (like a loader animation). It's possible to achieve what you're saying by removing the keyframes that are after 50%, instead taking the opacity to 0 by 100%.